# Not able to configure WCF-SQL Adapter in BizTalk 2016

Tags: wcf, biztalk, biztalk-2016

I am getting below error message while creating a WCF-SQL Adapter in BizTalk 2016. Previously I had same error message while configuring host instances for the WCF-Custom adapter and that issue was resolved by changing the machine name to FQDN. Now the machine name is also updated I am still facing same issue. Can someone please guide me.

[image]

Comment: This has a similar issue: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/66f67d94-8e05-4657-a246-206ef57d5ef5/error-during-configure-of-mqseries-adapter-send-and-receive-handlers?forum=biztalkr2adapters

Comment: This is not really a BizTalk error. Your computer isn't trusted by the network. Search for "The trust relationship..." and resolve that issue. Then this should go away

Answer (score 0):

The above issue is resolved. This was really not a biztalk issue. Like my previous question I unconfigured and reconfigured the biztalk once again, deleted the databases and started from first. This resolved my issue. One thing to notice is you should use fully qualified domain name while configuring the BizTalk. If something even if one of the bit is wrongly configured you have to the rework again.